# Getting strange error this.grid is undefined ext-all-debug.js (line 47393)

Tags: extjs

I have an editor grid

```
Grid.Selection = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel, {
layout:'fit',
border:false,
stateful:false,

initComponent: function() {        

    Ext.apply(this, {
        // {{{
        store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
            id: 0,
            fields: [ ...],
            data: []
        })
        ,cm: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
            // specify any defaults for each column
            defaults: {
                sortable: true // columns are not sortable by default           
            },
            columns: [
                rowNumberer, 
                combo1,
                combo2,
                combo3,
                itemDeleter]
        })
        // }}}
        ,plugins: new Ext.ux.plugins.GridValidator()
        ,viewConfig: {forceFit: true}
        ,sm: itemDeleter
        ,height: 150
        ,frame: true
        ,clicksToEdit: 1
        ,tbar: [{
                text: 'Add New Association'
                ,id: 'addBtnGrid'
                ,iconCls: 'icon-plus'                    
                ,listeners: {
                    click: {scope: this,fn: this.addRecord,buffer: 200}
                }
            }]
    }); // eo apply       


    // call parent
          Grid.Selection.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
} // eo function initComponent
// }}}
// {{{
,onRender: function() {
    // call parent
    Grid.Selection.superclass.onRender.apply(this, arguments);        
} // eo function onRender
// }}}
// {{{
,addRecord: function() {
    record = this.store.recordType;
    rec = new record({
        ...
    });
    this.stopEditing();
    this.store.insert(0, rec);
    **this.getView().refresh(); // GETTING ERROR ON THIS LINE**
    this.getSelectionModel().selectRow(0);
    this.startEditing(0, 0);
} // eo function addRecord    

,reset: function() {
    this.store.removeAll();
    this.addRecord();
}
}); // eo extend


// register xtype
Ext.reg('selectionGrid', Grid.Selection);
```

I add this grid to a form.
When I display the form I reset the grid which removes all records from the store and add a single new record.
But when this.getView().refresh(); is called I get

this.grid is undefined
this.grid.stopEditing(true); ext-all-debug.js (line 47393)

The item deleter plugin [http://code.google.com/p/extensive/s...eleter.js?r=13] is also calling 
grid.getView().refresh() but it works.

I will be highly grateful if somebody can guide me.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was due to the fact that the grid was not completely rendered before I was calling getView().refresh().

The solution was to call the above method after the grid was rendered.